# Switching two contacts with 24VDC potential difference

Tags: relay, 5v, parallel-port

This question relates mainly to the means of operating a relay module using a PC parallel port. I have outlined the application that this is to be used with but that is provided for background so users can get an overall picture - it is not part of my actual question.

I want to join two interface connections to an existing electronic device in order to actuate it. One pin (I'll call it P_ground) is grounded and the other (= P_operate) is at +24 VDC above ground. The device (an entrance turnstyle) is actuated by grounding the P_operate (24V potential) pin.   I do not know the turnstyle's internal circuitry, but grounding P_operate is the standard method of actuation.

I have a +5VDC powered relay module that I wish to use to ground pin Poperate when required.

I wish to use the LPT (printer) port of a computer to operate the relay module. I bought [**a relay module**](http://www.robotistan.com/1-way-5v-relay-module-tekli-5v-role-karti) that triggers with logic 0.
I have been unable to make the relay switch.

[[RM:]] This is the heart o the problem - the referenced relay module requires a high (not low)level to operate. ]]

I connect `Vcc` to +5v of adapter, `GND` to Negative(-) pin of the adapter...when I connect `In` pin to `GND` it should switch but it does not.   How could I make it to work?

**_______________________________________________**

This is NOT the actual turnstile used but shows the general sort of device that I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: You have to connect In to +5V (preferably through a resistor) to make the relay change states.

Comment: Follow the links to the examples from that site, and you will find that the code examples provide a logic level 1 to switch the relay on.

Comment: Nobody asking why he wants to short 24V to ground? Or are we just being mean and letting him do it?

Comment: Short circuiting  something can be dangerous.I don't recommed you do that unless you and the environment  around you are safe from the possible harm.Also,I'd be make sure I don't need the equipment afterwards if I were you.

Comment: I wrote a program to control entrance of swimming pool with card. Whenever user card is read i should let user pass in and to let user pass i should have short circuited 2 pins of tourniquet system. that is how it works i didnt invent that system. i tested it and works when 2 pins short circuited. i see this forum comments fast but no solution only adding problems to asked questions.

Comment: is it so hard to get help to make a relay work ? i am good at programming but not good at electronics.

Comment: It is extremely hard to get a relay to work if people give you the EXACT correct answer and then you ignore the answer and saythings that make you SEEM rude to people. I know you are frustrated, but you MUST read and understand what people say. See what JRE said an hour ago and see my answer below.

Comment: "Tourniquet" would probably translate better as ["turnstile"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile)

Comment: @GökhanKeskin Its better if you try and do some research before asking questions, and then ask. Electronic switch circuit would be a good start. Then ask if its right. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why on earth do you want to short 24V?

Comment: @Alex He's wishing to use a relay to connect two points which have a potentiaal difference of ~= 24VDC. "Short circuit" is traanslation from Turkish of "switch" or "connect".

Comment: Ohh, thanks for clearing that one up! thought he was mad...

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackExchange SE.You will find many helpful and useful people here and superb technical resources. You and your programming expertise are very welcome here.
With no intention of being rude, I strongly feel that it is worthwhile for you to note that you need to get used to how things are done here. Failure to do this will attract downvotes from people (not usually from me) who have strict ideas re the need to show that you are taking notice of the input that people have taken time to provide.  It is usual for people to make comments and ask questions when what you write is unclear and/or less clear than you may realise.  You need to read and pay attention to answers and comments given. Simply insisting that people do things in the manner that you want them to leads to downvotes and/or people ignoring your questions.

**The answer you wanted**

- Was in the very first comment, written very shortly after you posted the question.
- AND also in the 2nd comment posted an hour later.

For some reason you ignored this answer twice.

**THE ANSWER:**

If you had read and noted what JRE says above and looked at the Arduino code on [The example page provided](http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/tutorial-control-of-relay-module-by-garagino-and-serial-command) you would have seen that to make the relay operate:

**JRE:**

- You have to connect it to +5V (preferably through a resistor) to make the relay change states. And ...
- Follow the links to the examples from that site, and you will find that the code examples provide a logic level 1 to switch the relay on.

ie to turn the relay on you need.

- digitalWrite(relay,**HIGH**);

1e

- The relay is turned ed on by a high / +5V / level = 1 signal.

---

**Switching:**

Those relay modules and ones like them are relatively low quality - not utter junk, but also not super high quality. As shown in the photo, the relays used ARE rated for 24 VDC operation, but it is near the upper end of their range. Minimising current surge and anything liable to make them form an arc across the contacts should be avoided. Switching an inductive load at 24 VDC will probably destroy them quickly or immediately. Take due care. Ask if uncertain.

[image]

---

**STYLISTIC WARNING:**

The devices shown below are also called "Turnstiles" (despite not turning and not being stylish) by some, and serve much the same purpose as the rotary sort. Attempting to sprint through the open "gate" while pulling an excessively heavy wheeled bag behind can result, should the gate 'shut' just prior to passage, in the puller hitting the gate and folding over it. The following bag if suitably heavy will then do its darndest to push the puller over the barrier. Regardless of whether the transition attempt succeeds or fails, a significant degree of pain will ensue. Not recommended.
[Ask me how I know :-) :-(.]
Knowing why anyone should have this happen will probably require an offlist email :-).

[image]